# Given Key Not Present in Dictionary Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

Im working on data binding for a Xamarin forms project using Xaml for the UI.
So far its very simple:

XAML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
```

```
xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:Watson.ViewModels;assembly=Watson"
         x:Class="Watson.Views.DeviceCheck">

<ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <viewModels:DeviceCheckViewModel/>
</ContentPage.BindingContext>

    <!--<ActivityIndicator Color="Red" IsRunning="True"
                   x:Name="loadingScreen"/>-->
<StackLayout>
    <Label Text="Checking Device.."/>

    <Button Text="page nav"
            Command="{Binding NextButton}"></Button>
</StackLayout>
```

The code behind:

```
namespace Watson.Views
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class DeviceCheck:ContentPage
    {

    private DeviceCheckViewModel viewModel;
    public DeviceCheck() {
        InitializeComponent();

        BindingContext = viewModel = new DeviceCheckViewModel(this.Navigation);


    }// end of constructor     

}// end of class

}// end of namespace
```

This is trying to bind to a view model and use a binding command to go to another page on a button click.
The error I am getting is 'The given key was not present in the dictionary', this is when attempting a build. I have isolated the problem to the line: `<viewModels:DeviceCheckViewModel/>`

I have no idea why this error is occurring.

This is the view model:

```
namespace Watson.ViewModels
{
    public class DeviceCheckViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public INavigation Navigation { get; set; }
        public ICommand NextButton { protected set; get; }

    public DeviceCheckViewModel(INavigation navigation)
    {
        this.Navigation = navigation;
        this.NextButton = new Command(async () => await GotoNextPage());

    }

    public async Task GotoNextPage()
    {

        await Navigation.PushAsync(new RegisterDevice());
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this,
                new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
}
```

The reason I am pursuing this route is to adhere to the MVVM architecture.
So putting page navigation in the code behind is not really an option.
Also just a note, all the models, view models and views are in a folder structure with the same names.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You set the binding context in your code behind:

```
BindingContext = viewModel = new DeviceCheckViewModel(this.Navigation);
```

So there's no need to do the xaml-way, too. This also creates an instance of `DeviceCheckViewModel` and sets it as binding context:

```
<ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <viewModels:DeviceCheckViewModel/>
</ContentPage.BindingContext>
```

**But**, therefore it needs to have a parameterless constructor. This may be the reason for the excepetion you get.

Comment: So do you recommend deleting the xaml binding context? and keeping the code behind?

Comment: This actually fixed it. I just knocked out the Xaml markup for binding context and left the code behind version of binding context. Thanks for the help mate.

Comment: I usually like to have the xaml markup for binding, so I can use intellisense in the xaml. When I have to do a viewModel with parameters and don't want a parameterless constructor being called too, I'll put in the xaml mark up, do my code, then either remove it or comment it out and put the binding in code behind after the fact.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an older thread but when faced with the same issue I was not satisfied that the given answer was really acceptable for me. I also prefer to keep this type of binding in the markup; keeping the code behind to a bare minimum.

**What worked for me was to remove the XamlCompilation(...) attribute on the code behind class. Try to remove this attribute from your DeviceCheck class.**

I've also noticed that most of the code behind classes have this attribute but it only gives the issue on some of them.